# Mostrar un campo dependiendo del valor de otro. Formularios Django

Tags: django, formularios, vistas

Muy buenas a todos. Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar elementos en un formulario en Django. Tengo 2 modelos, uno llamado `Recurso` y otro llamado `Sesion`, los cuales están relacionados de tal manera un recurso pueda tener varias sesiones disponibles, con la particularidad de que esta asociación "Recurso - Sesiones" solo se produzca en los recursos que sean del tipo 'Por Sesiones'.

Lo que tengo que conseguir y no encuentro la manera por ningún lado en internet es que cuando cambie el valor del selector del campo "tipoRecurso" del formulario, se muestre el widget de elección de sesiones. Si no, no.

Código de los modelos:

```
class Sesion(models.Model):
    horaInicial = models.TimeField()
    horaFinal = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sesión"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sesiones"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.horaInicial)

class Recurso(models.Model):
    SESIONES = 'SE'
    COLA = 'CL'
    RECURSO_TIPOS = (
        (SESIONES, 'Por Sesiones'),
        (COLA, 'En Cola'),
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    tipoRecurso = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices = RECURSO_TIPOS)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, related_name = "divisionRecurso")
    precioA = models.FloatField()
    precioB = models.FloatField()
    precioC = models.FloatField()
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', null = True)
    sesiones = models.ManyToManyField(Sesion, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Recursos"
        verbose_name_plural = "Recursos"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)
```

Código del formulario:

```
class RecursoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Recurso
    fields = ['nombre', 'descripcion', 'tipoRecurso', 'precioA', 'precioB', 'precioC', 'imagen', 'sesiones']

    widgets = {
        'sesiones': FilteredSelectMultiple("Sesiones", is_stacked=False),
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RecursoUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuándo cambie? es decir que ¿Sólo si cambia se va a mostrar el campo? Creo que lo que buscas mas bien es mostrar u ocultar el campo para el usuario, lo cual refiere al frontend de la aplicación y no al backend. Eso puedes hacerlo con Javascript desde el template de la vista